# Linq GroupBy and Join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on some machine that "solving" problems of my clients.

This is how my client's problem looks like:

```
public class ClientProblem
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public string TaskToSolve { get; set; }
}
```

Once a-day I'm preparing List of all problems that I have to solve today. The list is looking like this:

```
List<ClientProblem> tasks = new List<ClientProblem>();

// Filling the list with task to be solved today

// list[0] = client 1 task 1
// list[1] = client 1 task 2
// ...
// list[n-1] = client 1 task n

// list[n+1] = client 2 task 1
// list[n+2] = client 2 task 2
// ...
// list[2n-1] = client 2 task 2n

// ...
```

The problem that I get is the problems of client N only at the end of solving all the problem of other clients. This makes client N starving.

I'm want to mix all problem, without starving clients. 
The solution should looks like this:

```
// list[0] = client 1 task 1
// list[1] = client 2 task 1
// ...
// list[n] = client n task 1
// list[n+1] = client 1 task 2
// list[n+2] = client 2 task 2
// ...
// list[2n] = client n task 2
// ...
```

I think I should use Linq GroupBy and Join methods.
Is that possible to solve this with Linq? Is there another effective solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After defining following extension method

```
public static class SomeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> InterleaveBy<T, S>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, S> selector)
    {
        return input
            .GroupBy(selector)
            .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => new { key = i, value = x }))
            .OrderBy(x => x.key)
            .Select(x => x.value);
    }
}
```

You can use it as

```
var newList = tasks.InterleaveBy(c=>c.ClientID).ToList();
```

if you have list of lists then

```
var newList = tasks.SelectMany(x => x).InterleaveBy(c=>c.ClientID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to group the tasks by client ID, and then interleave the groups. I'm afraid LINQ has no interleaving method, but you can create your own, e.g. like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Interleave<T>( IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences )
{
    var enumerators = sequences.Select( s => s.GetEnumerator() ).ToArray();
    while ( true )
    {
        foreach ( var e in enumerators )
        {
            if ( e.MoveNext() )
            {
                yield return e.Current;
            }
            else
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method assumes that all sequences are of the same length; if that is not the case, you'll want to add a flag indicating whether any elements were returned by the enumerators and make the loop condition depend on that instead of using a `yield break` as soon as one sequence ends.